# How can I get NSManagedObject from NSExpression?

Tags: nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

I have this predicate:

```
DG == <DG: 0x8c8dbd0> (entity: DG; id: 0x8c91140 <x-coredata://5F7ECBA0-D9B4-489A-85DA-3BE10A8D65CB-94947-00026842BC158909/DG/p2> ; data: <fault>)
```

How can I restore NSManagedObject from `comparisonPredicate.rightExpression.constantValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to my own problem was instead of use this kind of predicate: `@"DG == %@"`, I use now that: `@"DG.objectID == %@"`, and of course the argument is not the NSManagedObject but the NSManagedObjectID.